# Use MutationObserver compare old and new text content

Tags: jquery, mutation-observers

I need to compare the text within the children of an element from before and after the change occurred. I can get the function to trigger using the below script and return the new value but I also need to be able to access the old value.

```js
$('#changeButton').click(
  function() {
    var currentValue = parseInt($('#changingElement').text())
    $('#changingElement').text(currentValue+1);
  }
)


$(function() {
    var parentOfChangingElement = document.getElementById("changingElementParent");
    var alertOldAndNewValue = function() {
      alert("I'm unsure how I get the 'old' value");
      alert('New value: ' + $('#changingElementParent').text());
    }
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(e) {
      alertOldAndNewValue();
    });
    observer.observe(parentOfChangingElement, {
      subtree: true,
      childList: true
    });
});
```

```css
.button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: fit-content;
}
.button:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div id="changeButton" class="button">
  Click me to change value
</div>

<div id="changingElementParent">
  <div>
    <div id="changingElement">
      100
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If anyone has any ideas then I would be very grateful.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: See examples for `characterDataOldValue`.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579682/mutationobserver-new-value-in-the-format-of-oldvalue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you required to use Mutation Observer? Or is OK to use a global variable?

There are so many ways to do it... Bellow is the fastest solution. I can update it based on your feedback, therefore feel free to ask me anything in Comment section.

**The simplest way to keep track of previous value is to save it all the time at the end of processing function.**

In the example bellow, at the end of `changeButton` function, I just updated previousValue to be equal with newValue.

When the page initial loads, previousValue is equal with currentValue.

```js
// global variable
const changeBtn   = document.getElementById('changeButton');
const target      = document.getElementById('changingElement');


// Save previous_value in a data attribute, if global variables are not an option
target.dataset.previousValue = parseInt(target.innerText);

changeBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e){

    let previousValue = target.dataset.previousValue
        currentValue  = parseInt(target.innerText),
        newValue      = currentValue + 1;
    
    target.innerText = newValue;
    
    console.log('ClasicWay: previous value is ' + previousValue);
    console.log('ClasicWay: new value is ' + newValue);
    
    // all processing ended at this point, 
    // so we can update or previousValue to currentValue
    target.dataset.previousValue = currentValue;
})




//  Observer way
const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
      mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log("MutationObserverWay: previous value is ", mutation["removedNodes"][0]["nodeValue"]);
        console.log("MutationObserverWay: new value is ", mutation["addedNodes"][0]["nodeValue"]);
    });
});

    
observer.observe(
  target, 
  {
    childList: true,
  }
);
```

```css
.button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: fit-content;
}
.button:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div id="changeButton" class="button">
  Click me to change value
</div>

<div id="changingElementParent">
  <div>
    <div id="changingElement">100</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good way to do it and I expect it probably will work. Irrespective of processing power, is there a way for the mutationobserver itself to record both "states" of the element? I've seen documentation about "characterData" and "characterDataOldValue" values in the mutationobserver documentation but I've no idea how to use them. I'll mark your answer as correct but I'd really like to know if there is a local way to achieve this. Cheers!

Comment: The Observer Way was done by trial. The `characterData` and `characterDataOldValue` don't work in this case. I tried even converting the changingElement to an input and change its value to see if it catches it, but still doesn't. To better understand them I suggest the following: before first line of `console.log("MutationObserverWay...:` add a new one `console.log(mutation);`. Then open your console, trigger the change, and inspect the mutations listed in your console. Cheers!

Comment: Argh, as it happens I cannot declare a global variable in JS this piece of software (although, thinking about it, I might be able to append the value to a random element on the page and access it and edit it from there). Are there any other solutions you can think of?

Comment: @B.I. Of course there is mate. You can make use of data-XXX attributes to save values. Please check updated answer.